# How to fork a function with params in bash?

Tags: multithreading, bash, function

I'm new to bash scripting and I faced an issue when I tried to improve my script. My script is spliting a text file and each part of this text file is processed in a function ... Everything is working fine but my problem occurs when I'm forking (with &) my function processing ! My args are not like expected (it's a line number and text with whitespaces and backspaces) and I suppose it's because of global variables ... I tried to fork, then sleep 1 second in the parent thread and then continue in order to put args into local variables for my function execution but it doesn't work either ... Can you give me a hint about how to do it ? What I want is to be able to pass args to my function and be allowed to modify it after the fork call in my parent thread ... is it possible ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Parameters#
FILE='tasks'
LINE_BY_THREAD='500'
#Function definition 
function checkPart() {
    local NUMBER="$1"
    local TXT="$2"
    echo "$TXT" | { while IFS= read -r line ; do 
        IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
        #If the countdown is set to 0, launch the task ans set it to init value
        if [ ${ADDR[0]} == '0' ]; then
            #task launching
            #to replace by $()l
            echo `./${ADDR[1]}.sh ${ADDR[2]} &`  
            #countdown set to init value
            sed -i "$NUMBER c ${ADDR[3]} ${ADDR[1]} ${ADDR[2]} ${ADDR[3]}" $FILE
        else   
            sed -i "$NUMBER c $((ADDR-1)) ${ADDR[1]} ${ADDR[2]} ${ADDR[3]}" $FILE
        fi
        ((NUMBER++))
    done }
}
#Init processes number#
LINE_NUMBER=$(wc -l < $FILE)
NB_PROCESSES=$(($LINE_NUMBER / $LINE_BY_THREAD))
if [ $(($LINE_NUMBER % $LINE_BY_THREAD)) -ne '0' ]; then
    ((NB_PROCESSES++))
fi 
echo "Number of thread to be run : $NB_PROCESSES"
#Start the split sequence#
for (( i = 2; i <= $LINE_NUMBER; i += $LINE_BY_THREAD ))
do 
    PARAM=$(sed "$i,$(($i + $LINE_BY_THREAD - 1))!d" "$FILE")
    (checkPart "$i" "$PARAM") &
    sleep 1
done
```

My job is to create a scheduler for tasks described in this following file :

```
#MinutesBeforeLaunch#TypeOfProcess#Argument#Frequency#
2 agr_m 42 5
5 agr_m_s 26 5
0 agr_m 42 5
3 agr_m_s 26 5
0 agr_m 42 5
5 agr_m_s 26 5
4 agr_m 42 5
5 agr_m_s 26 5
4 agr_m 42 5
4 agr_m_s 26 5
2 agr_m 42 5
4 agr_m_s 26 5
```

When I'm reading a number > 0 in the first column, I just decrement it and when it's a 0 I have to launch the task and set the first number to frequency, last column ... 
My first code is the previous with sed for text replacement but is it possible to do better ?

Comment: Running multiple copies of `sed -i` on the same file at the same time is a recipe for disaster — you will end up with a mangled file.  However, putting that aside, your problem statement says "my arguments to the function are not what I expected", but you don't show what you get or what you expect, or what the sample data is supposed to look like.  I note that you don't refer to `$FILE` uniformly; the function should use that variable too.  Your script processes 500 lines per thread. For debugging (and SO) you need to scale back to 5 lines per thread, and 10 or 15 lines in the file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your answer, that's true I'm not using $FILE it's been changed :) My script processes 500 lines because with a small number of lines everything is working fine I'm not having any wrong results (because the 1 second sleep is covering the full function execution). That's true I'm not checking my args but I have to reconsider what you said about sed which seem more likely to be the issue !!

Comment: I've looked at it a little longer; I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.  You could/should use `awk` instead of `sed` (or even Perl, Python or one of their ilk).  As it is, your function invokes `sed` once per line in the file which is a performance disaster if the file is big enough to need splitting into 500-line chunks.  It depends on whether you're solving a problem for a class (and are constrained in what you can use) or are solving a problem in the real world and can use whatever tool is best for the job. You need to demonstrate a need to multitask the splitting process.

Comment: Yes it's true my file is going to be pretty big (10~15K lines) and using sed is not very performant but is it possible to do what I need to do with awk ? I need to do the following treatment :
For each line I decrement the first value if she is superior to 0 otherwise I run a command and copy the last value in replacement of 0

Comment: @Ko2r, chances are you can do what you want in native bash, with no `sed` _or_ `awk` at all; I'd try to cut out the forking entirely, as well, but need a better description of your actual goal before being able to help with a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated my post in order to provide you my file and my goal. I'd like to cut out the forking but the program must be efficient, and for the moment sed isn't ... I'm looking awk documentation to see if it's possible to do what I what I keep you in touch

Comment: You want to use a map/reduce sort of algorithm: each subprocess should generate its own chunk of data (tmp file), and return it to the main process which will put everything back together.

Comment: @didierc I didn't considered it but I can try ... I just have to return the new text to insert in the file and wait until the end for overwriting the file ...